# How to make iostat ignore snaps

Tags: snap, grep, loop-device

I am trying to filter out snap loop devices from iostat, while preserving the color formatting of the output.

I have tried the following:

```
iostat -y 5
iostat -y 5|grep -v loop
```

Neither option produce the desired output. **Without grep** I see too much noise from the snaps, **with grep** I lose the color formatting.

Current output `iostat -y 5` shows loop devices:

[image: results include loop devices]

Expected output (without loop devices and color coding still visible):
[image: expected output]

Comment: It's probably easier to provide the disks you do want to see, e.g. `iostat -y sda 5`

Comment: That works for me @Jos. I created an alias `alias iostat='iostat -y nvme0n1 5'` and it now works exactly as expected, though I will need to remember to tweak that alias if I add drives in the future.